# Cannot get Rspec tests to run with Capybara-webkit

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, capybara, capybara-webkit

It just won't start - any ideas?

Tried uninstalling and reinstalling QT (4.8.6), upgraded Xcode, brew doctor, checked settings in spec_helper - it's all correct.

Failure/Error: visit controls_path
     Capybara::Webkit::ConnectionError:
       /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/capybara-webkit-1.3.0/bin/webkit_server failed to start.
     # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/capybara-webkit-1.3.0/lib/capybara/webkit/connection.rb:75:in `parse_port'
     # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/capybara-webkit-1.3.0/lib/capybara/webkit/connection.rb:81:in`discover_port'
     # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/capybara-webkit-1.3.0/lib/capybara/webkit/connection.rb:62:in `start_server'
     # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/capybara-webkit-1.3.0/lib/capybara/webkit/connection.rb:25:in`initialize'
     # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/capybara-webkit-1.3.0/lib/capybara/webkit/driver.rb:17:in `new'
     # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/capybara-webkit-1.3.0/lib/capybara/webkit/driver.rb:17:in`initialize'
     # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/capybara-webkit-1.3.0/lib/capybara/webkit.rb:11:in `new'
     # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/capybara-webkit-1.3.0/lib/capybara/webkit.rb:11:in`block in '
     # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/capybara-2.4.1/lib/capybara/session.rb:79:in `call'
     # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/capybara-2.4.1/lib/capybara/session.rb:79:in`driver'
     # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/capybara-2.4.1/lib/capybara/session.rb:65:in `initialize'
     # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/capybara-2.4.1/lib/capybara.rb:248:in`new'
     # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/capybara-2.4.1/lib/capybara.rb:248:in `current_session'
     # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/capybara-2.4.1/lib/capybara/dsl.rb:46:in`page'
     # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/capybara-2.4.1/lib/capybara/dsl.rb:51:in `block (2 levels) in <module:DSL>'
     # ./spec/features/controls_spec.rb:17:in`block (3 levels) in '

Answer (score 1):

I honestly have no idea what finally made it work - but I got it working.

Uninstalled basically everything and reinstalled things piece by piece, but during it all I got lost on testing after a particular step and it started working without my noticing what I had just done.

When in doubt: reinstall I guess =/